# AngularJs - How to update dom element value from controller after ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am having

```
<uib-progressbar class="progress-striped active" value="100" type="warning" ng-hide="{{isLoaded}}"></uib-progressbar>
```

which i want to show this progress bar (ng-hide) until isLoaded is true..

and my script inside NameLists controller is

```
$scope.isLoaded = false;
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'services/getLists.php'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.isLoaded=true;
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
    {

    });
```

after the data loaded I have changed isLoaded to true but the progressbar is not hide.

Comment: have you made a controller for your view?

Comment: replace {{isLoaded}} with "isLoaded"

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 ng-hide="isLoaded"
```

Without the curlies.